# About the data alignment in c

Tags: c, memory, struct

And I define a struct :

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define O(type, field) (size_t)(&(((type *)0)->field))
struct byname {
int16_t int16;
int32_t int32;
int64_t int64;};
```

Then I use `sizeof(struct byname)` and it return 16 which I can understand.

However when I define the like adding a int8_t:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define O(type, field) (size_t)(&(((type *)0)->field))
struct byname {
int16_t int16;
int32_t int32;
int64_t int64;
int8_t int8;};
```

It just return 24, I think a int8 only takes 1 by and there are 3 bys padding according to data alignment, so I think the answer should be 20.

Anyone can kindly explain to me how the 24 comes?

Comment: It's because of padding

Comment: this will help you undersant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: The "duplicate question" is not the same as OP's question...

Answer (score 3):

The structure contains `int64_t`. If the compiler thinks that `int64_t` should be aligned to 8-byte boundary, it is reasonable to make the size of the structure multiple of 8 (therefore 24 bytes instead of 20) to align every `int64_t int64;` in an array of `struct byname` to 8-byte boundary.